# Free reader for RMKF Cobol database files

Tags: cobol

i have some dat files for powercobol starting with an RMKF tag at the begining of the file anyone know of a way to read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://www.cobolproducts.com/datafile/data-viewer.html

You might atleast get an idea of what the record layout is.

Comment: I found that didnt do me any good though.  Thanks for the suggestion.